# Looking for an existing ROS + Qt example

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently building a remote cockpit/basestation for my robot, and I was considering using ROS and Qt to do it.  I have a lot of experience using ROS, but this is definitely one of my first times using Qt.  We're fairly committed to Qt, but we're still trying to decide on a backend for our app.  ROS is definitely one potential option, assuming it slots in nicely with Qt.

The closest thing I've found to a ROS/Qt quickstart guide was (http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/roscreate_qt_pkg), but I was really looking for was a an existing ROS Qt package or application that I could run.

Does someone have an existing [and fairly crisp] ROS Qt application that they could point me to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10377/looking-for-an-existing-ros-+-qt-example/) by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 760 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2011-06-23**:
This question is somewhat related to: http://answers.ros.org/question/32/is-ros-still-looking-at-using-qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eros also has a package with qt versions of some of the roscpp_tutorials [eros_qt_tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_qt_tutorials). Note that although its in e(mbedded)ros, you don't have to be doing embedded to compile these - they compile just as well natively. They integrate ros/qt along with the .ui designer files so that its easy to build your layout.

You can [install eros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros/Installation) and build/run eros_qt_tutorials directly, or if you just want to check out the package code without all of eros and pull bits from that:

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/eros/tags/diamondback/tests/eros_qt_tutorials
```

The only special thing it uses is the eros_prepare_qt4 cmake macro (in CMakeLists.txt) which doesn't do anything special - it just helps patch a few corner case issues for static qt builds until the next cmake release comes out with some fixes.

If doing a shared library build, you can effectively replace that eros_prepare_qt4 with

```
# Add other components as you need them
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
# Need to pick up autogen'd ui files in build dir, so add the following
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest using PySide for Qt/ROS integration.  You need to install PySide from [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide::Downloads) first.

Here's a trivial example of publishing and subscribing to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('example')
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import String

from PySide.QtCore import * 
from PySide.QtGui import * 
import sys

class GUI:
    def __init__(self): 
        # A publisher for messages
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('example', String)

        # A subscriber for our own messages
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('example', String, self.sub_callback)

        self.button = QPushButton('push\nme')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.pub_callback)
        self.button.show()

    def pub_callback(self):
        self.pub.publish('Thank You!')
    
    def sub_callback(self, msg):
        print 'Got message:', msg.data
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the node
    rospy.init_node('example')

    # Initialize Qt
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = GUI()

    app.exec_()
```

You'll also need the following lines in your manifest.xml

```
<depend package="rospy" />
<depend package="std_msgs" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2011-06-27**:
My misunderstanding.  I've modified my answer to get rid of the "bad things" statement.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-06-27**:
Control of the main thread isn't an issue with c++ qt. The http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/roscreate_qt_ros_pkg script generates sources which allow gui and ros threads in parallel with clean shutdown from either. I haven't had any bad things happen with callbacks.